# Parallel inner product of a vector, using scan algorithm

Tags: opencl, parallel-processing

I have the optimized code for parallel (exclusive) scan algorithm, that's written in OpenCL.
I've read that inner (dot) product of a vector is based on parallel reduction but I was wondering is it somehow possible to use this already finished scan algorithm for the purpose?

Comment: Can you clarify what 'exclusive scan' is please? Is it like a histogram/count operation?

Comment: @mfa: [exclusive scan](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html) = [prefix sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum)

Comment: Are you able to post your scan code? since there are different optimizations, it's hard to suggest a way to integrate the dot product.

Comment: @J.B. dot product by defintion is a reduction algorithm. The reduction algorithm is not too hard to implement and every a moderately optimized version is much faster than a scan algorithm. It is best if you wrote a fast reduction algorithm that you can use.

Comment: @Pavan thanks, that's the clear answer I needed. Why didn't you put it as an answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dot product by defintion is a reduction algorithm. The reduction algorithm is not too hard to implement and even a moderately optimized version is much faster than a scan algorithm. It is best if you wrote a fast reduction algorithm that you can use.

Comment: This doesn't explain how to do a dot product with the finished scan data. I think it has to be done in the fist step of the scan, but it looks like there is no non-messy way to do them both in a single operation.

Comment: @mfa, The op wanted to know if scan algorithm is good for dot product and it is not. He just wanted my comment as an answer so he can accept it. We can talk about scan algorithm for dot product but that is a waste of `n` writes and ~n - log(n) operations.